# Google Maps Marker Pin Not Showing

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an issue with the Google Maps widget where the marker is not showing on my live site but is showing when I put the code into Codepen.

**Codepen:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxLprp

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD2X6alsV0XdrvNoB4HCEBxNn9VgQYniII"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.632566, -0.175259),
            zoom: 17,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: 51.632566, lng: -0.175259},
            map: map,
            title: 'Test'
        });

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="map" style="height: 300px; width: 300px"></div>
```

[image]

**Live Site:**

[image]

Would anybody possibly know what could be the issue here? The console does not show any errors.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript error on your live site?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.  What does the code/html/css that is on your site look like?  Are you using a CDN? What is on your site that isn't in the codepen?

Comment: No errors in console at all. Please see live site here - http://ts577563-container.zoeysite.com/contact-us - I'm using exact same code from the Codepen link but using the CSS inline with` <style>` being the only difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#pix-fe .global-html .html-content * {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Remove this CSS rule from your page and it will work...

If you are trying to hide certain features from the map, don't do it with CSS. Do it with the map options.